# Exporting a compiled function for later use

Tags: compile

I wish to export compiled functions for later use. This means that I do not want the compiled function to be recompiled every time I reload it. It also means that if my compiled function was for example `Listable`, then the function should still be `Listable` when I reload it.

Below I will present some attempts to save and reload the following function.

```
function = 
  Compile[{{x, _Real}}, Sum[Sin[Cos[-x^2*i]], {i, 1, 10^6}], 
  CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, 
  Parallelization -> True];
```

### Attempt using `.wdx` file

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]]
Export["compiled.wdx", function];
function[Range[10]] // AbsoluteTiming//First   
(* 0.191019 seconds *)
```

Now after restarting the kernel, we get

```
SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
function2 = Import["compiled.wdx"];
function2[Range[10]] // AbsoluteTiming//First
(* 0.310031 seconds *)
```

Of course this difference in timing is unacceptable - it seems the function is now recompiled every time it is called.

### Attempt using `LibraryGenerate`

Our example function `function` accepts lists, because we used `RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}`

```
function[{1, 0}]
(* {-0.2982909888387981, 841470.9848238959} *)
```

We now try to save this function as follows:

```
Needs["CCodeGenerator`"]
LibraryGenerate[function, "Myfun"]
```

And load it again:

```
function3 = LibraryFunctionLoad["Myfun", "Myfun", {Real}, Real]
```

There are two problems when using this method of exporting the function.

1. It seems that even if you do not compile to C code when you export as mentioned above it compiles to C code because if the function is not compiled to C code after loading it, it gets as fast as a function compiled to C code.
2. The more important issue is that now the function won't accept a list as its argument:

   ```
   function3[{1, 0}]
   ```

> LibraryFunction::cfsa: Argument {1,1} at position 1 should be a
>       machine-size real number. >>

Comment: At a guess, it's because you're exporting the Mathematica code to compile the function, not the compiled function itself. So the extra time comes from recompilation.

Comment: The C code generated will be in a directory as .dll file, you need to find that, and perhaps you can load it with `LibraryLink`. Or you can put the compilation command as an initialization cell to run when you open the notebook.

Comment: By directory, it'll be a temp/working directory.

Comment: Di you manage you export the compiled function? I read the documentation but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Instead of using the `Listable` attribute, try `{x, _Real, 1}` and submit your variable as a tensor.

Comment: Currently you're passing a tensor to C code that expects a single value.

Comment: As for Point 1, yes, `LibraryGenerate` creates C code, so it will be compiled...

Comment: @blochwave You do not like the blockquote environment (yellow background thingy) for output I see. I suppose the question is closer to the original after your edit.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom sorry, just personal preference regarding the quotes! Thanks for tidying up the question for reopening though - good job!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is inspired by my recent answer to [Save a C compiled function without losing the blessing of C compiler](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/82990/save-a-c-compiled-function-without-losing-the-blessing-of-c-compiler/82993#82993).

---

The key point here is to retain the `{Listable}` attribute of the compiled function. This is difficult as this attribute is stored in the Mathematica definition of the function, rather than the compiled C code, so neither `Export`/`DumpSave` or `LibraryGenerate` can store both pieces of information.

Instead we have to save the Mathematica definition of the function, and also locate the compiled library (e.g. `*.dll`) so that we can reload that rather than recompiling.

---

First, let's define an example listable function.

```
func = Compile[{{x, _Integer}}, 
         Module[{j = 0}, 
           Do[j++, {i, 10^8}]; 
           x*j],
        CompilationTarget -> "C", 
        RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}]

func[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.44 seconds, {1*10^8, 2*10^8, 3*10^8, 4*10^8, 5*10^8}} *)
```

The next step is to extract the location of the library created by this compilation (which is what I did in the linked question) and copy it to a new location, such as the current notebook directory.

```
funcLoc = func[[-1, 1]]
newfuncLoc = ToString@NotebookDirectory[] <> FileNameTake[funcLoc, -1]
CopyFile[funcLoc, newfuncLoc, OverwriteTarget -> True]
```

Now let's save the definition of `func` and the location of the library, and reload it.

```
DumpSave["compile.mx", {func, newfuncLoc}];
Clear[func, newfuncLoc]
<< compile.mx

func[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 2.59 seconds, {1*10^8, 2*10^8, 3*10^8, 4*10^8, 5*10^8} *)
```

Herein lies the problem, as this is significantly slower. But remember, we also saved the location of the C library, so let's link that file back into a new function:

```
funcNew = ReplacePart[func, {-1, 1} -> newfuncLoc]
funcNew[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}] // AbsoluteTiming
(* 1.40 seconds, {1*10^8, 2*10^8, 3*10^8, 4*10^8, 5*10^8} *)
```

There we are - the benefit of compilation to C is restored, and the `{Listable}` attribute remains.

Comment: How would you use this in a package?