# Save a C compiled function without losing the blessing of C compiler

Tags: export, compile, save

Consider the following example:

```
generatef[opt_: "MVM"] := 
 Compile[{}, Module[{j = 0}, Do[j++, {i, 10^8}]; j], CompilationTarget -> opt]

f1 = generatef[];
f2 = generatef["C"];

f1[] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.262879, 100000000} *)
f2[] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.495352, 100000000} *)

DumpSave["test.mx", f2];

Clear[f2]

<< test.mx

f2[] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {1.295921, 100000000} *)
```

*Tested in v9.0.1, Win8.1 64bit, TDM-GCC 4.9.2, `"SystemCompileOptions"->"-Ofast"`.*

Apparently `f2` is no longer compiled in C after the save & load, which is undesired. Any solution?

Comment: C compiled is not Mathematica code. There's a function CreateLibrary or something like this to create a dll from mm code. Unfortunately you cannot compile many functions in a single dll.

Comment: @faysou happily MMA creates a library for us when compiling which we can reload!

Comment: Yes, CreateLibrary is practical to know where to export the library.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, there is! Mathematica creates a `LibraryFunction` when compiling to C, but puts it in a temporary directory. If you can recover the library, you can load it as often as you like!

First let's define the function as in the question:

```
generatef[opt_] := 
 Compile[{}, Module[{j = 0}, Do[j++, {i, 10^8}]; j], CompilationTarget -> opt];
f2 = generatef["C"];
```

Now take the expression `f2`, and replace the heads of `CompiledFunction` and `LibraryFunction` with `List`. The last bit tells us all the information we need to load function again with [`LibraryFunctionLoad`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html):

```
f2List = (f2 /. {CompiledFunction -> List, LibraryFunction -> List})

(* {{10, 10.1, 5468}, {}, {{2, 0, 2}}, {{0, {2, 0, 0}}, 
    {100000000, {2, 0, 1}}, {1, {2, 0, 4}}}, {0, 8, 0, 0, 0}, 
    {{6, 0, 2}, {6, 1, 3}, {6, 0, 5}, {3, 4}, {6, 2, 6}, 
    {12, 6, 4, 7}, {6, 7, 2}, {4, 5, 3, -3}, {1}}, 
    Function[{}, Module[{j = 0}, Do[j++, {i, 100000000}]; j]], Evaluate, 
    {"...\\Mathematica\\ApplicationData\\
      CCompilerDriver\\BuildFolder\\compiledFunction0.dll", 
     "compiledFunction0", {}, Integer}} *)
```

So now all we need to do is load up the library and run it, with next-to-no-difference in the timing.

```
f2[] // AbsoluteTiming
(* {0.589635 seconds, 100000000} *)

AbsoluteTiming[
    mynewfunction = LibraryFunctionLoad @@ Last@f2List;
    mynewfunction[]
]
(* {0.584785 seconds, 100000000} *)
```

Then you need to copy the file out of the temporary directory to a directory of your choice in order to preserve the DLL. Here I've chosen the notebook directory, but you could also put it in one of the directories in `$LibraryPath` instead and then only have to specify the filename rather than a path.

```
CopyFile[f2List[[-1, 1]], ToString@NotebookDirectory[] <> "compiledFunction0.dll"]
myf2 = LibraryFunctionLoad[
  ToString@NotebookDirectory[] <> "compiledFunction0.dll", 
      "compiledFunction0", {}, {Integer}];
```

In this example, the `{}, {Integer}` refers to the input and output variables as per the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LibraryFunctionLoad.html), which will obviously be different for different functions.

The final point to note is that trying to overwrite/delete the copied DLL can throw an error if you haven't unloaded the library function via `LibraryFunctionUnload` first.

I've not tested it on OSX or Linux, but apart from the file extensions (`.dll`, `.dylib`, `.so`) I presume it should all be the same.

Comment: Exemplary answer! +1

Comment: +1. Perhaps also note that there is a directory that `LibraryFunctionLoad` automatically searches, so that one can specify a short name of a library, rather than a full path.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom yes good point - one could copy the file to that instead.

Comment: +1. BTW it's a little surprising to me that the default `Directory[]` isn't included in `$LibraryPath`.

Comment: Actually there's no need to use `LibraryFunctionLoad`, the only necessary part is to save the DLL to a non-temporary directory. Then one can save & load `f2` and recover the C compiled function with something like `f2new = ReplacePart[f2, {-1,1} -> (* The file path of the DLL  *)]`. In this way the `RuntimeAttributes` of the compiled function will also be recovered so your answer will be fully apply to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/58108/1871) :D

Comment: @xzczd it is actually necessary to use `LibraryFunctionLoad`; the `LibraryFunction` in the `CompiledFunction` will not work unless you do. There is no error but the library is not initialized and will not be used otherwise (only the bytecode), because `LibraryFunction` objects are stateful (which is not surprising when one thinks about it). I [wrote about it](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2011/Oct/msg00011.html) on *MathGroup* back in 2011.

Comment: @OleksandrR. Er…are you sure? I just tested the code in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/83266/1871), and `funcNew` apparently makes use of the DLL even if I restart _Mathematica_: http://i.stack.imgur.com/gIqig.png

Comment: @xzczd not in version 8, which was the current version when I wrote to the *MathGroup*. I suppose someone might have seen my message or noticed the behavior themselves, because it seems to have been fixed in version 9.

Comment: How would you use this in a package?