# Strategies and practical advice for using saved compiled functions in a package

Tags: packages, compile

I want to use a compiled function in a package without having to rebuild it each time. This slows down unit testing and loading of the package.

I have used the example in the link as my starting point:
[Exporting a compiled function for later use](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58108/exporting-a-compiled-function-for-later-use)

Briefly

1. Execute `func=Compile[...]` in a **notebook**
2. Save the `.dll` `funcLoc = func[[-1, 1]]` in the package location
3. Save `func` as `originalFuncDefinition.mx` with `DumpSave`
4. In the **package** do `Get["originalFuncDefinition"];` to expose the function symbol.
5. In the package redefine `func` as

```
PackageExport["func"]
func = ReplacePart[func,{-1, 1} -> funcLoc ];
```

Problems I feel I have with my approach

1. I write packages in an IDE and steps 1-3 being in a notebook are not available to IDE for editing / refactoring making debugging difficult down the line.
2. Steps 1 to 3 are difficult to automate as if you have several functions, you need to `DumpSave` the symbols one by one eg `DumpSave[{func1, func2 ...}]` you cannot pass it as a list eg `funcs = {func1,func2,...}; DumpSave/@funcs`
3. Step 4 exposes all the original definitions globally...
4. ...So I am not always sure which `func` is being used
5. This involves working back and forth between the notebook and the package making sure that `funcLoc` tallies to each `func` making it prone to error

Any advice, tips or ways to think about this would be appreciated.